# jQuery show submenu if parent have been clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Could some one please help with code.

**I want to show the submenu only when submenu parent is clicked.**

HTML

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
</ul>
```

So if you click on the parent submenu will show.

Here is fiddle link - http://jsfiddle.net/KhNCV/1/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$('.sub-menu').hide();

$("li:has(ul)").click(function(){

$("ul",this).slideDown();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3nigma/KhNCV/2/

OR

```
$('.sub-menu').hide();

$("li:has(ul)").click(function(){

$("ul",this).toggle('slow');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3nigma/KhNCV/4/

Comment: good one but how to hide the last clicked sub-menu. Now It is displying both

Answer (score 2):

Here's [your example working](http://jsfiddle.net/2ws48/2/). It's unclear why you need the `a` tags, as you could use cursor: pointer in the CSS to make the `li` appear clickable. I'll assume you want to do some spiffy hovering on them in IE that's CSS only? If not, you could simplify by removing them.

Instead of doing hide() on .submenu, you should use CSS (parsed with DOM instead of onReady/load).

```
.sub-menu { display: none; }
```

And then here's you code to toggle the menus:

```
$('ul li a').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('ul.sub-menu').toggle();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: but how to hide previous sub menu because now both are displaying

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.sub-menu').hide();

$("a").click(function(){

    $(this).parent().children("ul").toggle();

})
```

check out this link
 http://jsfiddle.net/KhNCV/6/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('li a').click(
function() {
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function(){

   //Hide all the sub menus
   $('.sub-menu').hide();

   $("li:has(ul)").click(function(){
      //Find the child ul and slideToggle
      $(this).children("ul").slideToggle();
   });
});
```