# Submenu on click

Tags: jquery, wordpress, submenu

I found the very good question [jQuery show submenu if parent have been clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232176/jquery-show-submenu-if-parent-have-been-clicked?rq=1) here on StackOverflow. Then I made a jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/JtAeh/4/ to try it out with my css and html. It worked! But in the wordpress theme I'm using, they've got some script that overrules my new custom script.

Is it possible to overrule a script in a parent theme with a custom script in a child theme in an elegant manner?

Or else: How can change this script:

```
var mobile_menu = function() {
        if( $(window).width() < 600 && $('body').hasClass('responsive') ) {            
            $( '#nav > ul, #nav .menu > ul' ).mobileMenu({
                subMenuDash : '-'
            });

            $( '#nav > ul, #nav .menu > ul' ).hide();
        }
    }
    mobile_menu();

    var show_dropdown = function()
    {        
        var options;              

        containerWidth = $('#header').width();
        marginRight = $('#nav ul.level-1 > li').css('margin-right');
        submenuWidth = $(this).find('ul.sub-menu').outerWidth();
        offsetMenuRight = $(this).position().left + submenuWidth;
        leftPos = -18;

        if ( offsetMenuRight > containerWidth )
            options = { left:leftPos - ( offsetMenuRight - containerWidth ) };    
        else
            options = {};

        $('ul.sub-menu:not(ul.sub-menu li > ul.sub-menu), ul.children:not(ul.children li > ul.children)', this).css(options).stop(true, true).fadeIn(300);    
    }

    var hide_dropdown = function()
    {                               
        $('ul.sub-menu:not(ul.sub-menu li > ul.sub-menu), ul.children:not(ul.children li > ul.children)', this).fadeOut(300);    
    }

    $('#nav ul > li').hover( show_dropdown, hide_dropdown );
```

to this neat script:

```
$('ul li a').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('ul.sub-menu').toggle();
    return false;
});
```

?

I tried to change `.hover` to `.click` and `.fadeIn(300)` to `.toggle` but it was a long shot and didn't work.

Hope someone is able to answer this question.

Comment: Try Appending your script once the page is loaded.this will ensure that your script will overrule wordpress script

Answer (score 0):

You could try removing any other event handlers on the hover or click event (whichever is appropriate before you add yours:

```
$('ul li a').unbind('click').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('ul.sub-menu').toggle();
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I got some help from the theme developer. He sent me this script which turns the menu into a click-menu and not a hover menu:

```
var show_dropdown = function()
    {
        if( $( this ).children( 'ul').length > 0 ) {
            var options;

            containerWidth = $('#header').width();
            marginRight = $('#nav ul.level-1 > li').css('margin-right');
            submenuWidth = $(this).find('ul.sub-menu').outerWidth();
            offsetMenuRight = $(this).position().left + submenuWidth;
            leftPos = -18;

            if ( offsetMenuRight > containerWidth )
                options = { left:leftPos - ( offsetMenuRight - containerWidth ) };
            else
                options = {};

            $('ul.sub-menu:not(ul.sub-menu li > ul.sub-menu), ul.children:not(ul.children li > ul.children)', this).css(options).stop(true, true).fadeIn(300);
            return false;
        } else {
            window.location = $(this).children('a').attr('href');
        }
    }

    var hide_dropdown = function()
    {
        if( $( this ).children( 'ul').length > 0 ) {
            $('ul.sub-menu:not(ul.sub-menu li > ul.sub-menu), ul.children:not(ul.children li > ul.children)', this).fadeOut(300);
            return false;
        }
    }

    $('#nav ul > li').toggle( show_dropdown, hide_dropdown );
```

Now I will try to tweak it a little more to get a submenu to hide when another one is opened... thank you for your answers.