# JavaScript not working to show submenu if parent have been clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I've found this [jQuery show submenu if parent have been clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232176/jquery-show-submenu-if-parent-have-been-clicked) but when I tried to incorporate it to my pre-made HTML page, the code does not seem to worked in a sense that it shows the submenu right away and it does not toggle to hide the sub menus, I have tried to create a separate JSP file and link it to my main HTML page but it does not work

```
<script src="test.js"></script>
```

so I just added this script below to my HTML page, which does not work as well

```
<script>
$('.sub-menu').hide();

$("li:has(ul)").click(function(){

$("ul",this).toggle('slow');
});
</script>
```

I am not well versed with JS coding so I would need some guidance on how I can incorporate the codes properly, below is my code where I have added the code that I'm trying to use

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.sub-menu').hide();

$("li:has(ul)").click(function(){

$("ul",this).toggle('slow');
});
});
</script>

    </head>

    <body class="oneColFixCtrHdr">

    <div id="container">
    <div id="header" style="background-color:#7BD12E">
    <h1 align="Left" style="color:#FFF; font-size: 18px;"><strong>Test</strong></h1>
      <!-- end #header --></div>

    <div id="mainContent">
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    </ul>
        <!-- end #mainContent -->
    </div>

    <div id="footer" style="background-color:#7BD12E">
    <p style="color:#FFF">Test</p>
    <!-- end #footer --></div>
    <!-- end #container --></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to wrap the jquery in a `$(document).ready()`:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.sub-menu').hide();
    $("li:has(ul)").click(function(){
        $("ul",this).toggle('slow');
    }); 
})
```

and i would move it to just before your closing `</body>` tag as well

and as per BrettL's comments, you need to add the jquery library

Comment: You also need to add the jQuery library in your code. Place <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script> before any other javascript on your page.

Comment: If you move it just before the closing `body` tag, there's no need to wait for the ready event, is there?

Comment: @JuanMendes I always do anyway just to make sure the dom is ready before the scripts are run

Comment: "I always do anyway" is not a very good reason. All script tags are loaded synchronously, unless they have the defer attribute, which the ready event doesn't wait for. The reason to call `$.ready` is to guarantee that the HTML is loaded. By putting it just before the close body ag, you're guaranteed that the HTML has loaded. The main reason for putting scripts after the HTML is so the HTML can be displayed before the scripts are parsed.

Comment: thanks for the prompt response guys...that definitely did the trick...all suggestions were applied and it works!!!

Comment: @JuanMendes I always do anyway wasn't my reason - my reason was just to make sure the dom is ready as I have had occasions where I haven't wrapped it and it's run the scripts too early - don't ask me how that happened if what you're saying is true about the html being parsed