# How can i hide and display the sub-menu's on click using event listener or set event

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, dom, event-listener, c3.js

```js
if ($C.getElement(".side-bar")) {
    $C.setEvent("click",".side-bar",function() {
        var x = this.childElementCount;
        alert(x);
        if ( x == 2){
            var y =        this.selectAllChildren.className;
            alert(y);
        }
        /*if(Ele.style.display == "block"){
            Ele.style.display = "none";
            //alert("bro...it works,you dont see me?,i'm inside if loop");
        }
        else {
            Ele.style.display = "block";
            //alert("bro...i'm working fine");
        }*/
    });
}
```

```css
ul,li{
  list-style:none;
  }

.side-bar ul{
  display :none;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <ul>
    <li class="side-bar">Menu title 1
      <a>  </a>
      <ul> 
        <li>item 11 </li>
         <li>item 12 </li>
         <li>item 13 </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="side-bar">Menu title 2
      <a> </a>
      <ul> 
        <li>item 21 </li>
         <li>item 22 </li>
         <li>item 23 </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
 </html>
```

in the above function i'm trying to create a menu `on click` using set event ,but i cannot find out an appropriate solution.the sub menus need to be displayed when click on the main item.how can i fix it without changing the html and css part?

Comment: What is the used library?

Comment: If you're using jQuery then there is a answer already. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8232214/5788489

Comment: no this is not jquery

Comment: Let's attract code igniter experts with a little tag ...